# $digest already in progress

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm fetching the data using $http.get() and passing it as argument to a custom filter to get the filterd data. But it is giving an 
error: **$digest already in progress**.

Does anyone know how to avoid this error or achieve the same thing but a different way?

```js
var map=angular.module('map', [])
.controller('mapCtrl', function ($scope,$filter,$http) {
 $http.get('./json/integrated.json').success(function(data) {
     $scope.sitesInfo = data;
   });
 var filteritems= $filter('applySfotwareFilter')($scope.sitesInfo);
  
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should place

```
var filteritems= $filter('applySfotwareFilter')($scope.sitesInfo);
```

inside your success function;

What happens is the filtering starts before your data is ready.

Comment: Even better might be to move the filter to the UI where it is require. usage of $filter in the controller always seems a little icky to me

Comment: true, it looks neater in the UI. However, it can be more efficient to place the filter in the controller, rather than having it slow down the application in a long ng-repeat. But that's another debate altogether...

Comment: @Aditya if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.